# How do I do Custom Alert Action Sheet?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a mail API which sends some information and document. I send only Files documents but I want to show one more choice in UIDocumentPickerView.

How can I show the list " document , photos , camera etc." in the same picker with images ?

My code is :

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    let urlData = url as URL
    let theFile = urlData.absoluteString
    self.documentName.text = "\(theFileName)"
}

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public func documentMenu(_ documentMenu:     UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {

    documentPicker.delegate = self
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mySpecialFunction(){
    let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
    importMenu.delegate = self
    importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Provide some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a custom component, you need to code it yourself of find something similar on GitHub or [CocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls?platform_id=ios).